# OpenGL loading binds the last loaded texture to all textureID's

Tags: c++, opengl, loading, texture-mapping, texture2d

So my problem is that I try to load multiple textures at start up and then store all of the ID's so that I can bind them to use them. Now I know that the ID's are being stored correctly because I can debug it and see in both assigning and usage that the ID's are the same. Just for every binding it uses the last texture that I load. Here is my code:

```
GLuint TextureLoader::LoadTexture (const char* fileName,Material& material,int width,int height) {
    GLuint textureImage;

    FILE* textureFile;
    textureFile = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    unsigned char* imageData;

    if (textureFile == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    imageData = (unsigned char*)malloc(width * height * 3);
    char header[54];
    fread(header,1,54,textureFile);
    fread(imageData, width * height * 3, 1, textureFile);

    fclose(textureFile);

    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i) {
        int nextIndex = i * 3;
        unsigned char a = imageData[nextIndex];
        unsigned char b = imageData[nextIndex+2];

        imageData[nextIndex] = b;
        imageData[nextIndex+2] = a;
    }

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures( 1, &textureImage );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureImage );
    glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    /*glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );


    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData );*/
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    free(imageData);

    return textureImage;
}
```

Here is my usage of this code:

```
if (showTexture) {
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, material.texture);
}
```

Here is my load call:

```
green1.texture = TextureLoader::LoadTexture("/Users/hewitt/Desktop/OpenGLImages/face6.bmp",green1, 256, 256);
```

And then I just use:

```
glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f);
```

to draw depending on the corner it changes. And this draws the one texture correctly it just repeats the texture even when I glBind a different number.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit ----------

```
glBegin(mode);
            Spatial::Vector3 normal = Mesh::calculateNormal (pointGroup);
            glNormal3f(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);

            Material material = mesh.getMaterial();

            if (showTexture) {
                glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, material.texture);
            }

            int counter = 0;
            for (Spatial::Vector3 point : pointGroup) {
                if (showTexture == false) {
                    Material::Colour colour = material.getColour();
                    glColor3f(colour.red, colour.green, colour.blue);
                } else {

                    if (counter == 0) {
                        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f);
                    } else if (counter == 1) {
                        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,1.0f);
                    } else if (counter == 2) {
                        glTexCoord2f(0.0f,1.0f);
                    } else if (counter == 3) {
                        glTexCoord2f(0.0f,0.0f);
                    }
                }

                glVertex3f(point.x,point.y,point.z);
                counter ++;
            }


            glEnd();
```

Comment: What do you mean "then I just use"? That function by itself doesn't do anything. Show the relevant part that actually draws things. My guess that you were screwed by the legacy immediate API and tried to rebind the texture from within `glBegin/glEnd`, which you cannot do.

Comment: @ybungalobill I added the change.

Comment: You should really check the result of `glGetError()`. In your case you would have gotten a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` for every function that is allowed to be called between `glBegin/glEnd`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot call `glEnable` or `glBindTexture` while in between `glBegin` and `glEnd`. You must bind your texture before `glBegin`. In fact the set of OpenGL functions you can call between `glBegin` and `glEnd` is limited to those transferring vertex attributes (`glVertex`, `glColor`, `glTexCoord`, etc...).

Note that the immediate mode API (that is `glBegin`/`glEnd` and friends) is legacy and was deprecated for more than 10 years. I suggest you switch to the modern OpenGL pipeline, that will sort many things out for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was such an easy fix

Comment: Also yea I know but for this spec we have to do it for opengl 1.1. Don't ask y not a clue.

Comment: @Hewiiitt Probably some old code the university keeps from whoever did it in the first place... Hopefully they'll change it.